# Something is causing my 12V ignition wire for the stereo not to function

Tags: ford, car, audio, wiring, wiring-diagram

I have 2002 ford focus and I installed a new stereo system it was working fine.... then I had to pull the stereo out again b/c I forgot to install Mic. and cig lighter.... after I hooked those things up I went to push the unit back in...... and the stereo went dead......

At first, I thought it was a fuse or relay

so I check fuse box under the steering wheel..... Nothing Blown

Then

check the fuse box under the hood...... Nothing Blown

So that was all good

SO FUSES AND RELAYS ARE GOOD.........

Is there a third fuse box under dash????

The New stereo unit has two wire harness inputs

One for speakers and audio

Second one is for POWER (((( PROBLEM))))))

(Consist of )

*GROUND

*12V BATTERY WIRE

*12V IGNITION WIRE

((((I tested this one with a volt meter and it was dead even when key turned)))))

I crossed the *12V IGNITION WIRE & *12V BATTERY WIRE

The Stereo Unit powered on....

Something is causing my 12V ignition wire for the stereo not to function

Any ideas

Comment: How did you check the fuses? Visual only?  Also, it's certainly *possible* there's another fuse - perhaps an inline one.  Was the previous radio an aftermarket? IME, those are more likely to have an inline fuse than a factory radio.  Can you physically inspect the wiring back from the radio to the power source?

Comment: I checked the fuses visually with a flashlight.  The wire goes from the dash into the firewall no clue after that.  I wish I had 2002 Ford Focus Electrical Wiring Diagram. The previous radio is Factory original but I notice today that radio no longer turns itself off or on. I cant inspect the wire cause no clue were it goes and its wrapped in protective foam

Comment: Check with a ohm meter / continuity checker

Comment: Does the car run? If so, then I'd doubt that the fuses for ignition are blown... Unless that's not exactly what it is.

Comment: car runs and drives

Comment: The fuse has nothing to with allowing the engine to run. It's on a circuit that is meant to provide power to items that one wants to power only when the ignition is in the ON position.

Comment: Thank you so much.... it ended up being the cluster accessory (fuse 41) tested with amp tester it was shot

Answer (score 3):

The ignition 12v wire has a fuse blown most likely, recheck your fuses. Fuses F31 (ign 30A) and F41 (Battery 7.5A) in The Central junction fuse box, behind dash panel LH side, may be concealed behind the knee panel.

Comment: Are the fuses you stated match my 2002 ford focus

Comment: According to my repair information, yes.

Comment: any others to check that would affect the 12V IGNITION WIRE

Comment: Thank you so much.... it ended up being the cluster
accessory (fuse 41)  tested with amp tester it was shot

Comment: @MIKE Please upvote and mark my answer as solution, thanks.

Comment: Fuse F41. Thats the Acc wire. Happened to me aswell.